# How can I use fs.createReadstream with fs.promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, stream, fs

I use `require("fs").promises` just to avoid to use callback function.

But now, I also want to use `fs.createReadstream` to attach a file with POST request.

How can I do this?
Or what alter createReadstream in this case?
Or should I use `require("fs")`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So by using `const fs = require('fs').promises;` you're only gaining access to the promise version of the `fs` module. According to spec, there is no equivalent `createReadStream` entry in the [File System Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promises_api). If you want that functionality, you'll need to store a reference to it in addition to the promisified version of fs.

I'd encourage anyone reading this to use the following at the top of your file to include both the promises api and ability to createReadStreams.

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const createReadStream = require('fs').createReadStream;
```

Your creation of readstreams will look like this (note no longer includes a prepended `fs.`):

```
createReadStream('/your/path/here');
```

Equally important to note:

According to spec, you'll eventually want to use the following instead (disclaimer, current out of box node can't do this without certain flags/dependences)

```
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';
```

Comment: using Node.js v17.1.0 I'm getting error that createReadStream is not a function

Comment: @user2677034 According to spec, `createReadStream` is [still there in node 17](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v17.x/api/fs.html#fscreatereadstreampath-options). Nothing came to immediate mind on what's causing what you are seeing. You may want to post what you're seeing in a new question if you were not able to resolve it yet.

Answer (score 4):

I do it like this:

```js
import { promises as fs, createReadStream } from "fs"

await fs.mkdir("path...");

const buff = createReadStream("path ...")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can "promisify" it like this:

```
function streamAsPromise(stream) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let data = "";        
        stream.on("data", chunk => data += chunk);
        stream.on("end", () => resolve(data));
        stream.on("error", error => reject(error));
    });
}

const text = await streamAsPromise(createReadStream('file.txt'));
```

Notice the `await` will wait until the *whole* file is read before resolving the promise, if the file is very big might be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit broad, but I can point you to some helpful package. It doesn't cover nearly all functions, but the package [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) automatically makes a lot of `fs` functions return a promise, I definitely suggest that. Then you can always just use the regular `fs` at the same time. As for the `fs.createReadStream()` you'll probably be wanting to just wrap what you need in a `new Promise()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an equivalent function in the promises API called [`filehandle.createReadStream([options])`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlecreatereadstreamoptions). However, how it works is slightly different from the standard implementation. You first need to open a file handle and then you can call `createReadStream` on that handle. Here is an example:

```js
const file = await fs.open('file.txt', 'r');
const stream = file.createReadStream();
```